# Simple form_for in the root page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to do a "simple form" in my root page in order to update a field in a table.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :trig, label: "your Trigram", :required => true %>
    <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block'%>
<% end %>
```

My route :

```
root 'static_pages#cvpage'
put '/' => 'users#update'
```

In my users controller :

```
def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @user.update_attributes(user_params)

    if @user.save
       redirect_to cvsindex_path
    end
end

def user_params
    params.require(:users).permit(:trig)
end
```

But that doesn't work. My app goes to the blank page `/users/6` Do you have any idea?

Comment: `bootstrap_form_for` is Ruby gem ?

Comment: yes I use it in order to have beutiful form. It work in all my other forms

Comment: can you try resources :users, only: [:update] in routes.rb and remove put '/' => 'users#update'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `<%= bootstrap_form_for @user do |f| %>` to `<%= bootstrap_form_for @user, :url => '/', :method => 'PUT' do |f| %>`

Your `resources :users` should come after `put '/' => 'users#update'`

`<%= form_for @user %>` always make path of new if `@user` object is new record AND update id object is already exist.

As a good practice you should not use root path like this. Because for updating you can use any path instead of root_path.

Comment: Yes, need to give the path explicitly. Otherwise `form_for` will do its own logical assumptions..

Comment: I just want to do a form on the root page that launch update method in the user controller

Comment: As per your comment you need a form on root page. With that form you want to call update action of users controller. Is this what you want ?